# What causes the error to fire in an Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

So, I need to make an Ajax request for each stock symbol entered into a text box. In my ajax request, I attempt to send a string holding one symbol to my servlet. Unfortunately, when I attempt to make my request, the error message fires. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(event){

            var singleStock = $('#stocks').val();
            var stocklist = singleStock.split(" ");
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<stocklist.length; i++){
                doAjaxRequest(stocklist[i]);
            }


         });
    });

function doAjaxRequest(data) {
    // replace the ??? with appropriate values      
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                url : "./QuoteServlet", 
                data : {"stock":data}, 
                dataType : "json",
                success : drawTable, 
                error : alert("Error")
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `error:` parameter must be a function. You're calling `alert()` unconditionally before you send the AJAX request, and setting the `error` parameter to what it returns.

```
function doAjaxRequest(data) {
    // replace the ??? with appropriate values      
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                url : "./QuoteServlet", 
                data : {"stock":data}, 
                dataType : "json",
                success : drawTable, 
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error: Status: "+textStatus+" Message: "+errorThrown); }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Then your service most likely isn't returning valid json, but the fix mentioned in this answer was DEFINITELY needed.

Comment: I've changed the error function to display the actual error. What's it showing now?

Answer (score 0):

The error param needs to be a function, try this

```
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST", 
            url : "./QuoteServlet", 
            data : {"stock":data}, 
            dataType : "json",
            success : drawTable,
      error: function() {
         alert ("error");
          }
          });
```